# Pseudocode for PHP into Tornado/Python

Tags: php, python, tornado

I am very used to working with PHP – creating a new .php file, typing in everything, intermixing it with some HTML, include/requiring different .php/.html files etc.

I just started learning to work with Tornado, and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the basic principals and constructs Tornado is built off of.

To begin to understand how exactly much of Tornado works (other than, yes, of course, reading their documents), I am trying to take something basic to me in PHP and recreate it in Tornado.

For example, in PHP, I have my `index.php` page. On that page I have an `email` input and `password` input. When the user submits the form, the `action` is set to `login.php`, we are sent to `login.php` where the "login function" is called which authenticates the user. If all is good, the `$_SESSION` variable is set, and they are logged in. If there is an error, an error message appears on `login.php`

What would be the equivalent "pseudocode" for this in relation to Tornado?

Some basic, highly imperfect python:

```
import os

import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop

root = os.path.dirname(__file__)
port = 8888

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html")

class LoginHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("login.html", title="Login to your account!")

    def post(self):
        useremail = self.get_argument("useremail", None)
        password = self.get_argument("password", None)
        self.render("login.html", title="Login to your account!")

def main():
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
        (r"/login", LoginHandler),
        (r"/css/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": os.path.join(root, 'css')}),
        (r"/pictures/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": os.path.join(root, 'pictures')}),
    ])
    application.listen(port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any help on my conversion here is greatly appreciated. It's just a very different way of doing things than I'm used to, and pseudo-code for simple a process like this would definitely help. Anyway, thanks all.

Answer (score -1):

you can use [react](http://reactphp.org/) its a Event-driven, non-blocking I/O with PHP.

Here is an example of a simple HTTP server listening on port 1337:

```
<?php

  $i = 0;

  $app = function ($request, $response) use (&$i) {
      $i++;

      $text = "This is request number $i.\n";
      $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'text/plain');

      $response->writeHead(200, $headers);
      $response->end($text);
 };

 $loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
 $socket = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
 $http = new React\Http\Server($socket);

 $http->on('request', $app);

 $socket->listen(1337);
 $loop->run();
```